# What is the DocuSign API for receiving the email failure notification

Tags: docusignapi

What is the DocuSign API for receiving the email failure notification.
e.g wrong email domain, or email address doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct endpoint to know if there was any email failure notification, instead you can use below endpoint

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/1764240/envelopes/<envelopeId>/recipients
```

to check the envelope' recipient status, you will find response like:

```
"signers": [
    {
        "name": "Signer1",
        "email": "docusign.sso11abc@gmail.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "recipientIdGuid": "da2b543a-4e3c-4944-bbdf-9acfbe356f38",
        "userId": "c8eacb9e-f6b9-40f4-b2fb-450a0763d579",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        **"status": "autoresponded"**
    }
]
```

More details for this endpoint is available at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/

There is another recommended way to get the notification using DocuSign connect, where DocuSign will push an XML message to you on the registered URI for the subscribed events, in your case for Recipient Delivery Failed. More details on DocuSign Connect is available at https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf